# Can't Configure Apache Shiro with MySQL, SHA256 Password Hashing Algorithm, Salting in Base64 String

Tags: configuration, shiro, salt, password-hash

I am trying to configure Apache Shiro using shiro.ini in order to authenticate users against MySQL Database where all credentials are saved.  Passwords are hashed using sha256 algorithm and a salt per user is used and saved/recovered from MySQL database. I would like to avoid creating custom Realm and custom SaltedAuthentificationInfo which i believe is possible through shiro.ini proper configuration
**Or not??** Is this possible?
Can i avoid using custom Realm and SaltedAuthentificationInfo??

To register users i implemented the following function

```
    @POST
    @Path("new")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String create(User requestBody) {

        System.err.println("NEW User");

        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName(requestBody.getFirstName());
        user.setLastName(requestBody.getLastName());
        user.setEmail(requestBody.getEmail());

//             Do Something With Salt Per User Random Generation or Something like it
//================================================================================================================
        RandomNumberGenerator rng = new SecureRandomNumberGenerator();
        String salt = rng.nextBytes().toBase64();
        String hashedPasswordBase64 = new Sha256Hash(requestBody.getPassword(), salt, 1024).toBase64();
        user.setSalt(salt);
        user.setPassword(hashedPasswordBase64);

        boolean result = userDAO.persist(user);
        userDAO.closeEntityManager();

        if (result) {
            return ReturnResults.results(new ArrayList<User>(asList(user)));
        }
        return "{}";
    }
```

My shiro.ini:

```
[main]
ds = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource
ds.serverName = 127.0.0.1
ds.user = **********
ds.password = **********
ds.databaseName = **********

jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = false

jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = "SELECT password, salt FROM User WHERE email = ?"
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = "SELECT role_name FROM UserRole WHERE email = ?"
# jdbcRealm.permissionsQuery = "SELECT permission FROM RolesPermissions WHERE role_name = ?"

authc.usernameParam = email
authc.passwordParam = password
authc.failureKeyAttribute = shiroLoginFailure

credentialsMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.Sha256CredentialsMatcher
#credentialsMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher
credentialsMatcher.storedCredentialsHexEncoded = false
# credentialsMatcher.hashAlgorithmName = SHA-256
credentialsMatcher.hashIterations = 1024
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $credentialsMatcher

passwordService = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService
passwordMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.PasswordMatcher
passwordMatcher.passwordService = $passwordService


shiro.loginUrl = /authentication/login

cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager

sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager.sessionIdCookieEnabled = false

ssl.enabled = false

securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm
strategy = org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.FirstSuccessfulStrategy
securityManager.authenticator.authenticationStrategy = $strategy

[users]

[roles]

[urls]
/authentication/login = authc
/authentication/logout = logout

/doctors/* = authc

/users/new = anon
/users/details/* = anon
/users/* = authc
```

*My DB Schema*:

[image: DB Schema]

My Implemented Transfer Objects:

User

```
package gr.histopath.platform.model.TransferObjects;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region = "EntityCache")
public class User {
    private long id;
    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String password;
    private String salt;
    private boolean activated;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "email")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "firstName")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "lastName")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "password")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "salt")
    public String getSalt() {
        return salt;
    }

    public void setSalt(String salt) {
        this.salt = salt;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "activated")
    public boolean getActivated() {
        return this.activated;
    }

    public void setActivated(boolean activated){
        this.activated = activated;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return id == user.id &&
                Objects.equals(email, user.email) &&
                Objects.equals(firstName, user.firstName) &&
                Objects.equals(lastName, user.lastName) &&
                Objects.equals(password, user.password) &&
                Objects.equals(salt, user.salt) &&
                Objects.equals(activated, user.activated);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, email, firstName, lastName, password, salt, activated);
    }
}
```

UserRole Transfer Object:

```
package gr.histopath.platform.model.TransferObjects;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region = "EntityCache")
public class UserRole {
    private int id;
    private String roleName;
    private String email;

    @Id
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "roleName")
    public String getRoleName() {
        return roleName;
    }

    public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "email")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        UserRole userRole = (UserRole) o;
        return id == userRole.id &&
                Objects.equals(email, userRole.email) &&
                Objects.equals(roleName, userRole.roleName) &&
                Objects.equals(email, userRole.email);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, email, roleName);
    }
}
```

Finally my login() function:

```
 @POST
    @Path("login")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public boolean login(Authentication authData) {
        System.out.println("Param email: " + authData.getEmail());
        System.out.println("Param password: " + authData.getPassword());
        UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(authData.getEmail(), new Sha256Hash(authData.getPassword()).toBase64());
        if (!subject.isAuthenticated()) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Trying to authenticate with token");
                subject.login(token);
                System.out.println("User [" + subject.getPrincipal().toString() + "] logged in successfully.");
                return true;
            } catch (UnknownAccountException uae) {
                log.error("Username Not Found!", uae);
                System.out.println("Username Not Found!");
            } catch (IncorrectCredentialsException ice) {
                log.error("Invalid Credentials!", ice);
                System.out.println("Invalid Credentials!");
            } catch (LockedAccountException lae) {
                log.error("Your Account is Locked!", lae);
                System.out.println("Your Account is Locked!");
            } catch (AuthenticationException ae) {
                log.error("Unexpected Error!", ae);
                System.err.println("Unexpected Error!");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

After calling `subject.login(token)` i get shiro error "Unexpected Error!"
Stack Trace:

```
Unexpected Error!
org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationException: There was a SQL error while authenticating user [mixtou@gmail.com]
    at org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm.doGetAuthenticationInfo(JdbcRealm.java:254)
    at org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthenticatingRealm.getAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticatingRealm.java:568)
    at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doSingleRealmAuthentication(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:180)
    at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doAuthenticate(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:267)
    at org.apache.shiro.authc.AbstractAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticator.java:198)
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.AuthenticatingSecurityManager.authenticate(AuthenticatingSecurityManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.login(DefaultSecurityManager.java:270)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.login(DelegatingSubject.java:256)
    at gr.histopath.platform.controllers.authentication.AuthenticationController.login(AuthenticationController.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:243)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:764)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:545)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:513)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:505)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:479)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3246)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3230)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setString(PreparedStatement.java:4025)
    at org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm.getPasswordForUser(JdbcRealm.java:281)
    at org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm.doGetAuthenticationInfo(JdbcRealm.java:221)
    ... 70 more
```

Any Ideas what i am missing or doing wrong??
Is my `shiro.ini` ok??
Is this possible without implementing custom classes for `Realm` and `SaltedAuthentificationInfo` ?? Most of the examples i have seen so far are implementing custom classes. However i haven't found any recent example using shiro 1.4

Any advice is very appreciated. I am banging my head two days now...

I don't know if there is any problem with dependencies, so i upload my pom.xml also.
**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <groupId>gr.histopath.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>HistopathPlatform</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging API + implementation: -->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>1.7.25</version>-->
            <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

         <!--https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.shiro/shiro-core-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.shiro/shiro-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.shiro/shiro-lang -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-lang</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.shiro/shiro-crypto-cipher -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-crypto-cipher</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.shiro/shiro-crypto-hash -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-crypto-hash</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>



        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.secnod.shiro</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>shiro-jersey</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>0.2.0</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-processing</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-sse</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--2nd Level Cache-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-jpamodelgen -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>io</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfa</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Could the problem be in my user registration code or with the mysql jdbc driver or with web.xml??

Comment: NOTE: duplicate post from the mailing list (for future googlers)
https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/shiro-user/201808.mbox/%3C1533194641872-0.post%40n2.nabble.com%3E

Comment: I posted it also there because for two day i got no answer and haven't solved my problem yet.  I am trying to get help from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely possible and is meant for this purpose. From what I see you are heading towards the right direction; However I see that you are using queries like

> SELECT password, salt FROM User WHERE email = ?
>   and SELECT role_name FROM UserRole WHERE email = ?

for authentication and roles. Can you confirm that `User` and `UserRole` are your table names? Note that using JDBC realm connects to your database using the specified datasource and performs **SQL queries** regardless of any persistance frameworks you have implemented.

Also, when you configure `shiro.loginUrl = /authentication/login` and `/authentication/login = authc` the `action` of the login form is intended to be empty. Hence no controller is required

```
@POST
    @Path("login")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public boolean login(Authentication authData) {.....}
```

to handle the security. The framework handles the part for you.

Comment: Yes i Confirm that User and UserRole tables exist in database. Do you have any working example using password hashing with shiro without implementing custom realm and SaltedAuthenticationInfo. Because i haven't found any

Comment: I have implemented a project with [https://docs.google.com/document/d/1g_6oDy-hDLX5cLEX7C2a80YUl_ffTHMoYBnIaCLAebA/edit?usp=sharing] these settings.

Comment: I tried your configuration but i still get the same exception java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Comment: This is the error i always get when i use apache shiro's realm and not my custom.

Comment: Could you share your table schemas?

Comment: I have uploaded a Db Schema Image.

Comment: I see that you have decided to implement your custom realm now. I think you have configured the application correctly. However the error lies in how you save the credentials in the database. Try:
`hashedPasswordBase64 = hashedPasswordBase64.toHex();` before saving it to database.

Comment: But i don't want to save the Hex i prefer to use Base64 values. I don't think that is the problem. I will try to use the default realm not my custom one and i will tell you what happens. I don't know if there is any problem with dependencies so i will also upload my pom.xml. Thanks for your replies